# Does $\left|A\right|=\left|\mathbb{N}\right|$ and $\left|\mathbb{N}\right|=\left|\mathbb{Z}^+\right|$ imply $\left|\mathbb{Z}^+\right|=\left|A\right|$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A$ is a countably infinite set. Is it true that if $\left|A\right|=\left|\mathbb{N}\right|$ and $\left|\mathbb{N}\right|=\left|\mathbb{Z}^+\right|$, then $\left|\mathbb{Z}^+\right|=\left|A\right|$?

It can be show by the Cantor-Bernstein theorem that $|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{Z}^+|$, as
\begin{align}
f&:\mathbb{N}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Z}^+, \ \text{as} \ f(x)=x+1\implies \left|\mathbb{N}\right|\leq\left|\mathbb{Z}^+\right| \\
g&:\mathbb{Z}^+\hookrightarrow\mathbb{N}, \ \text{as} \ g(x)=x-1\implies \left|\mathbb{Z}^+\right|\leq\left|\mathbb{N}\right|.
\end{align}
If we know $\left|A\right|=\left|\mathbb{N}\right|$ and $\left|\mathbb{N}\right|=\left|\mathbb{Z}^+\right|$, can we deduce that $\left|\mathbb{Z}^+\right|=\left|A\right|$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: generally, if you know $\lvert A\rvert=\lvert B\rvert$ and $\lvert B\rvert=\lvert C\rvert$, you can conclude $\lvert A\rvert=\lvert C\rvert$ because if $f:A\to B$ is a bijection and $g:B\to C$ is a bijection, then $g\circ f:A\to C$ is a bijection.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $A,B$ and $C$? e.g. not true if the sets are infinite or finite

Comment: My statement is universal.